# Meta Data Column doesn't match with source column names in Informatica Powercenter

Tags: oracle12c, informatica-powercenter, flatfilesource

I am loading data from a CSV Flat File into a target Oracle DB using Informatica. The Flat file contains Arabic Column Names and I happen to create the table with similar column names using double-quotes. But when running the map it gives me the above error i.e. Meta Data Column doesn't match with source column names.

If I change the names of the columns to English in the target table things are fine.

I found out that it is currently a bug in Informatica and will be resolved in the next release. We are using Informatica 10.2 and oracle 12c as the target.

Comment: This is strange, informatica file read process uses position or column separator. Anyways, in such case you can use sqlplus to load into database. Now, there can be rejects so you need to clean up before running sqlplus. Also, did you try loading data by skipping first row?